# AngularJS - Update data on different controller

Tags: angularjs

I beginning on this framework.
And I've a question about update a controller from another controller.

I know this question has many times asked.
But it's not like my problem.
I can resolve my problem with rootScope, but I don't like (Am I wrong ?)

This is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/1Lwg20wz/

I thought it would update automatically with this part of code:

```
this.article = articleService.article;
```

I would like to update my PanelController when I click on "Read news".
How do you do ?
What is the best practice ?

Comment: You are right. Avoid using $rootScope, so your code can be self contained. About your answer, I'm watching for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a couple of small issues in your example:

1. In the following HTML:

   ```
   <a href="#" ng-click="selectArticle(article.index)" class="btn btn-default">
       View news
   </a>
   ```

   Change `href="#"` to `href=""`. Otherwise it will navigate to the root of your application instead of executing the `ng-click`.
2. In the same HTML change `ng-click="selectArticle(article.index)"` to `ng-click="main.selectArticle(article.index)"`.

Now to the main issue.

In the `PanelController` you have the following code:

```
this.article = articleService.article;
```

This will copy the reference stored in `articleService.article` to `this.article`.

If `articleService.article` held a reference to the article object with id 1, `this.article` now also holds a reference to that object. They are however, two different references.

You have the following code to set the selected article object:

```
this.selectArticle = function(setArticle) {     
    articleService.article = articleService.articles[setArticle - 1];
};
```

Now `articleService.article` will hold a reference to another article object, for example with id 2. But, `this.article` in `PanelController` will still hold a reference to the article object with id 1.

The easiest solution to achieve what you want is to use the original `articleService.article` reference in your view, instead of creating a copy of it.

In `PanelController`

```
this.articleService = articleService;
```

In HTML:

```
<h1>{{panel.articleService.article.title}}</h1>
<p>{{panel.articleService.article.content}}</p>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7ccop2hy/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried to use `articleService` in view. I thought that I can access to `articleService` without to define in controller.